# Remove all files recursively without deleting directories

Tags: command-line, find, rm

I want to "clean out" all of the files a directory including all files in subdirectories but I want to leave the subdirectories in place. My understanding of `rm -r` is that it will also delete the subdirectories themselves.

I *do not* want to delete hidden (dot) files.

How can this be done?

Comment: `find -type f ! -name "[.]*" -delete` is not suitable?

Comment: I don't know. Does that do what I'm asking?

Comment: Try without `-delete` - it just print filenames to delete.

Comment: Do you want to delete files (hidden or not) in hidden directories?

Comment: What about symlinks to directories?

Comment: @Costas, `-type f` only includes _regular_ files (not symlinks, sockets, fifos, devices, doors...).

Comment: I quite happy with only including regular files here. In my project, I don't have any hidden directories so it's not a problem.

Comment: I had the same question, and it was properly answered: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1066026/how-can-i-recursively-find-a-directory-by-name-and-delete-its-contents-includin

Comment: For those of us who want to delete all files including hidden files, do this: `sudo find . -type f -exec rm {} +`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use `find` for that:

```
find . ! -name '.*' ! -type d -exec rm -- {} +
```

Comment: What is the difference between `-exec rm` and `-delete` here?

Comment: Not all find implementations have `-delete`

Comment: Some shells require escaping before `+` like `\+` and {} is better to put into quote `'{}'`

Comment: I do not see the reason to ignore hidden files

Comment: @RomeoNinov please read OP question: `I do not want to delete hidden (dot) files.`

Comment: @Costas, no, there's no shell that requires escaping `+` (at least not in the Bourne, csh or rc families). There's a legend that says that some old versions of `csh` required escaping `{}` but I've never come across those.

Comment: @ScottWilton, `-delete` is GNU (and some BSDs) only, `-exec rm` is standard (though less safe)

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas You are fully right (so as everytime). May be I am so oldschool to believe in legend ;)

Comment: @Costas, I strongly doubt that legend given that even the 2BSD (1978, where csh was first released) csh man page clearly documents _`{}` is passed undisturbed_.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, how are hidden directories and the files within them treated in this example?

Comment: @ScottWilton Hidden directories are included, but hidden files in hidden directories not. If you want to reject all files in hidden directories then `find . ! -name '.*' ! -type d ! -path '*/.*'` should do the job.

Comment: @jimmy, more like `find . -name '.?*' -prune -o ! -type d -exec rm {} +` to avoid descending in those altogether. Note that `--` is not necessary here (doesn't harm though) since paths start with `./`.

Answer (score 0):

try something like:

```
find <path> ! -name '.*' -type f -exec rm {} \;
```

Comment: Any reason why to remove the files one at a time instead of speeding things up with `.... -exec rm {} +`  ?

Comment: I prefer to do the things one by one. Mass (and parallel) operations have some time strange (and unpleasant) side effects (as make huge load on the I/O subsystem)

Comment: `-exec rm {} +` is not parallel, it just calls `rm` with several file names. It runs fewer `rm` invocations so is more resource-friendly. If it slightly less safe in that it enlarges the race window within which a directory component of the files to remove may be changed to a symlink. But only `-delete` or `-execdir rm {} \;` would fully address that.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas, non of these (-delete or -execdir) exist in UNIX. And I do not see in question to be mentioned linux!

Comment: @RomeoNinov, yes I said in another comment here that only `-exec` is standard. `-delete` and `-execdir` come from BSDs though, GNU added them about 10 years later. In any case, that has nothing to do with Linux, which is just a kernel.