# Remove files + files from subdirectories in Directory

Tags: rm

I would like to remove all files from a directory /data which includes 8 other sub directories.

Is there a command which will recursively clear all subdirectories but not remove the actual folders?

Comment: Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/182033/117549

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following would delete any non-directory files, like regular files, symbolic links, named pipes, sockets etc., in or under the `/data` directory:

```
find /data ! -type d -delete
```

For implementations of `find` that does not have the non-standard predicate `-delete`, use `-exec rm -f {} +` in its place:

```
find /data ! -type d -exec rm -f {} +
```

This would find all non-directory files in or under `/data` and would execute `rm -f` on as large batches of these as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Use find command

```
find /data -type f -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

will delete only files due to the type selection type f for files.

Comment: No need for -r if you're removing files...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `find` command for this.

To create a test case to reproduce your description, let me do this:
 1. `cd /tmp`
 2. `mkdir -p testing/{a,b,c}`
 3. `cd testing/`
 4. `touch {a,b,c}/{1,2,3}`

To verify there are multiple directories each containing multiple files:

```
$ find -type f
./c/3
./c/2
./c/1
./b/3
./b/2
./b/1
./a/3
./a/2
./a/1
```

You can now use `find` again to delete whatever it finds:

```
find -type f -delete
```

If you now run `find -type f` again it will not return any results, because the files are gone, but you can see that the directories still exist:

```
$ ls
a  b  c
```

The `find` command is very powerful. You can discover more about it using `man find`.

Comment: The question isn't yet tagged Linux, so I'll just note that -delete is a gnu extension to find.

Comment: @JeffSchaller Ah, noted. Thanks for that, it wasn't on my radar that `-delete` is a GNUism :)

Comment: @JeffSchaller, `-delete` is from FreeBSD (1996). Only added to GNU `find` in 4.2.3 (2004) (and to NetBSD find in 2007)

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas `-delete` was added in January 2017 to OpenBSD `find`, if you want to be complete...